# Return Placeholder in fields with input error (Contact Form 7)

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have some contact forms on my website (Contact Form 7).

When fields are filled in, but with an error the input stays the same as the user typed in. What I would like to have is;

When for example an user fills in his e-mailaddress, but which isn't valid because he didn't put in an @ or something like that, the field returns the placeholder for this input field, instead of the filled in input by the user.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give example of error? if entered invalid email Id , what error it gives?

Comment: This is my contact page:
http://aandagtvooru.nl/thuisgenoten/contact/

All it does is add a red, left-border and makes the text-color red

What I would like to happen is that the info you insert (for example, test - which isn't a valid input for emailadres) gets removed and the orignal placholder pops back up

Comment: it is giving **Check and adjust the highlighted fields, and then click again to send. for all validations.** You need field specific validation errors?

Comment: No, the error at the bottem of the field is okay.

What I would like to happen is, for example the input for the email field is unvalid - so instead of the input show, the placeholder gets placed back.

Comment: ok I see , you mean if any data is invalid then you want to set form as it was before error fired? Like in normal view.

Comment: Yes, exactly! But only for invalid fields.. If fields are  valid, the input should stay the same

Comment: it will require to customize plugin and need to add jquery to clear things.

Comment: But what code do I need to add?